# How to use list command in SVN to list files with a specific extension? e.g. .jar or .java

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I need a way to use svn list command which returns urls for files with specific extensions e.g..jar or .java. something like this if it exists:

```
svn list https://url-to/extrenal/repo [*.jar]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you:

1. to use the `-R` option for recursive search
2. to use `find` (on Windows) or `grep`(on Linux) to filter the results

I guess you're using Windows because of tag `tortoisesvn`.
So here is the command on Windows:

```
svn list -R https://url-to/extrenal/repo | find ".jar"
```

Comment: Thanks! It works and you are right, Im on Windows. My heart goes with the Penguin though ;-)

Comment: How can you exclude specific file extensions?

Comment: @ChristianTownsend Please look at the options of `find` command, especially the `/V` option displaying the lines that do no contain the specified string.